# Unable to load certificate in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificate

I am trying to read a certificate using OpenSSL that is generated by Google Play. The certificate is described as follows:

> The Base64-encoded RSA public key that is generated by Google Play is in binary encoded, X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE format.

I decoded the given Base64-encoded string into binary using OpenSSL from the command line using this:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d -A <<< THE_KEY_CONTENT > key.der
```

The binary file appears to be reasonable. It's 294 bytes and the first byte is `0x30` which I believe matches up with a `SEQUENCE`.

With the resulting binary file, I attempt to run the following command:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in key.der -out key.pem
```

But I get the following errors from OpenSSL:

```
unable to load certificate 140736245019656:error:0D0680A8:asn1
encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1199:140736245019656:error:0D06C03A:asn1
encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:767:140736245019656:error:0D08303A:asn1
encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested
asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:699:Field=serialNumber, Type=X509_CINF 140736245019656:error:0D08303A:asn1
encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:699:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
```

Is there something I'm missing to get this certificate loaded? I'm assuming Google wouldn't be giving me a bad certificate!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I interpreted the description to mean there was an entire X509 certificate contained within the `.der` file, when in fact it was *only* the RSA public key DER-encoded.

As a result, the correct command to issue turned out to be the following:

```
openssl rsa -inform der -in key.der -pubin
```